# iOS app with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput is crashing in App Store version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have an app which is using camera. In the last version, I've moved the camera control to a new class and it started to crash in the App Store version except the very first run. The app works as expected when installed through Xcode.

I have the following function to do the configuration.

```
func performConfiguration(block: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    sessionQueue.async { () -> Void in
        block()
    }
}
```

App is crashing in the line where I checking if video output can be added tot he session (line 6 below):

```
func configureVideoOutput() {
    performConfiguration { () -> Void in
        self.videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        self.videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self.delegate_voutput, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate"))

        if self.session.canAddOutput(self.videoOutput) {
            self.session.addOutput(self.videoOutput)
            let connection = self.videoOutput.connection(with: .video)
            connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate_voutput code:

```
    weak var delegate_voutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate?
```

I set the delegate_voutput in my view controller to "self" and implement delegate functions.

Here is the crashlog from App Store:

```
0  MyApp                          0x1003b921c closure #1 in CameraController.configureVideoOutput()
1  MyApp                          0x1003b9e90 partial apply for closure #1 in CameraController.performConfiguration(block:)
2  MyApp                          0x1003bd2c8 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x192ff8304 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
```

I have added `NSCameraUsageDescription` to info.plist and also the localized version (InfoPlist.strings) in case this was the reason..

I am not sure what is specific in the first launch as there is nothing stored in the hard drive related to the configuration.

Is there a way to test App Store behavior without submitting app for review? Will TestFlight give the same behavior?

Edit: Here is how `sessionQueue` is declared in `CameraController.swift`:

```
private var sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.mikrasya.myapp")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the architecture of the app by following Apple's AVCam example code which solved the crash.

It is still mystery why App was ok when installed using Xcode but crashed in App Store version.